# How to set margin for children

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I want to set top margin for image in the below code, how I can do that? Just designing a screen with text and image on the screen.

Here is my code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SizeConfig().init(context);

  return Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 160,
          left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
          right: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("images/bg_splash.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill)),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "App is allowing users to learn & Grow their Brains",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontSize: 25.0,
              color: Color(0xFFFDEA20),
              fontFamily: "Calistoga",
            ),
          ),
          Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
            height: 175,
          ),
        ],
      ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your image widget with padding

```
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
                height: 175,

              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `SizedBox(height: 10.0),` with your requirement in column above `Image()` widget

```
return Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 160,
        left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
        right: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image:
            DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("images/bg_splash.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "App is allowing users to learn & Grow their Brains",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
            fontSize: 25.0,
            color: Color(0xFFFDEA20),
            fontFamily: "Calistoga",
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
          height: 175,
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions for this

1. wrap your image with padding

> ```
> Padding(
>             padding: EdgeInsets.only(
>                           bottom: 12,
>                           top: 12,
>                           left:10,
>                           right:10),
>     
>                       child: Image(
>                         image: const AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
>                         width:125,
>                       ),
>                     ),
> ```

2. wrap your image with Container add margin property

> ```
>   Container(
>               margin: EdgeInsets.only(
>                  left: 10,
>                  right: 10,
>                   bottom:10,
>                   top:10),
>               child: Image(
>                 image: const AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
>                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
>               ),
>             ),
> ```